# Why does typescript not check the naming for the contents of an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I coded this interface:

```
interface IExamService {
    exam: IExam;
    exams: IExam[];
}  

interface IExam {
    current: boolean;
    id: number;
    name: string;
    subject: string;
}
```

and used it here:

```
class ExamService implements IExamService {

    exam: IExam;
    exams: IExam[] = [
        {
            current: false,
            id: 1,
            examId: 1,
            subject: 'x',
            name: 'Exam 1'
        },
        {
            current: false,
            id: 2322,
            examId: 2322,
            subject: 'y',
            name: 'Custom Exam 1'
        }
    ];
}
```

Can someone tell me why id does not flage the use of `examId` as an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript interfaces do not prevent you from adding additional properties. From the TypeScript Handbook:

> Notice that our object actually has more properties than this, but the
>   compiler only checks to that at least the ones required are present
>   and match the types required.
>   http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#interfaces

Your object conforms to the interface IExam. Adding an additional property doesn't stop your object conforming to the interface.

Comment: You may be interested in a potential proposal currently under discussion for [Strict Interfaces](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3755)

Answer (score 1):

just guessing here, wouldn't it only complain if you don't implement one of the properties of your interfaces ? Adding extra properties in addition to those defined by the interface doesn't look like a problem to me.